# How to position braces (decorations) in longtable?

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, longtable, tikzmark

I am trying to put braces into `longtable` (to span them on some rows). But if a table position on odd and even pages differs, there is a problem with vertical alignment of these braces (decorations):
[image]
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-5mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-13mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
    \toprule
    first column & second column%
    \smash{\tikz [remember picture] \node (rightmark) {};}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    B & \smash{\tikz [remember picture] \node (n1) {};} B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & \tikz [remember picture] \node (n2) {}; B%
    \tikz [overlay,remember picture]
          \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=2mm},decorate,thick]
          (n1.north -| rightmark.east) -- (n2.south -| rightmark.east)
          node [midway,right=4mm,rotate=90,anchor=north] {brace};\\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    D & \tikz [remember picture] \node (n3) {}; D\\*
    D & D \\
    D & D \\
    D & D \\
    D & D \\
    D & D \\
    D & D \\
    D & D \\
    D & \tikz [remember picture] \node (n4) {}; D%
    \tikz [overlay,remember picture]
          \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=2mm},decorate,thick]
          (n3.north -| rightmark.east) -- (n4.south -| rightmark.east)
          node [midway,right=4mm,rotate=90,anchor=north] {brace};\\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I tried to add a code for storing horizontal table position (immediately below the command with node putting):

```
\makeatletter
\ifodd\c@page
    \def\refmargin{\the\oddsidemargin}
\else
    \def\refmargin{\the\evensidemargin}
\fi
\makeatother
```

but after first line break command `\\` in the table the value of `\refmargin` can't be read.
How to get the proper position of `rightmark` node in MWE above (both on even and on odd page)?

Comment: I can't read tikz that well but probably the problem is that the heading is only evaluated once and re-used as a box, so the tikz remember there probably does the wrong thing, why does that need to be in the heading rather than at the point that you need the brace?

Comment: I looked for most transparent solution - in which for vertical alignment of braces only one node is used (I denoted it `rightmark`). Maybe I unnecessary complicated the way of putting the brackets - and I should span it on two nodes only, as you have suggested. Thanks.

Comment: This wouldn't work even if the header was evaluated on every page because `tikzmark` names must be unique. If the table spans more than one page, this won't be the case and will cause trouble if the header was evaluated more than once. [Just realised you're not using `tikzmark` but I assume the same thing applies.]

Comment: If you use **geometry** you ought never to set page layout dimensions manually but always use the package. Otherwise **geometry** doesn't know what changes you've made and so cannot take them into account, leading to likely weirdnesses.